# Weird behaviour of Mage::app()->getStore() in multistore configuration

Tags: magento-1.9, module, multistore

In multistore magento1.9.x configuration (*two stores in this case*) , when I call `Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId()` , from a module's controller, it always return **store Id** of the store having smallest **store Id**.

Things that I tried:

1. Execute controller from `https://<STORE_1_BASE_URL>/` and `https://<STORE_2_BASE_URL>/`.
2. Disabled store view of store 1 and modified **index.php** to redirect all request to store 2.

   `$_SERVER["MAGE_RUN_CODE"] = $STORE_2_CODE; 
    $_SERVER["MAGE_RUN_TYPE"] = $STORE_2_TYPE;`

So what is the default behaviour of `Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId()`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()` for getting current store id instead of `Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId()`

Comment: Is this behavior already known?  and where are these function implemented?

Comment: How can i specify the whole website instead of a specified single store in the multi-store website?   Code : $rootCategoryId = 2;